# how can I share variable in recursive class?

Tags: c#

I have the below class, I would like to be able changing the value of ever and have all the the recursive (the class declared inside the root) to the most updated value of it.

```
public class A
{
    List <A> ListA= new List<A>;
    int ever;

}
```

Comment: I honestly don't get what you try to achieve. Please pose a better example.

Comment: You could make it `static`.

Comment: Would like you to recursively evaluate what exactly you're trying to ask/achieve before posting in here :-)

Answer (score 0):

To have logic run when the value changes you need to use a *property*:

```
public class A
{
    List <A> ListA = new List<A>();
    private int _ever ;
    public int ever 
    {
        get {return _ever;}
        set {
                foreach(A a in ListA) 
                {
                    a.ever = value;
                }
            }
    } 
}
```

If there is only one "root" instance you could also make the field `static` - that way the value is associated with the *class* and not a specific *instance*.

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap the field with a property which sets the field as well as all of the items in the list.

Just be careful with this, because if you have any circular references, this will cause a `StackOverflowException`.

```
public class A
{
    private int _ever;
    private List<A> _list = new List<A>();

    public int Ever
    {
        get { return _ever; }
        set
        { 
            _ever = value;
            foreach (A a in _list)
            {
                a.Ever = value;
            }
        }
    }
}
```